# Example of the impact of statistical inference in society

Tags: history

When giving a talk or explaining my latest results, several colleagues of mine downsize the importance of the statistical analysis part as being "only statistics". In my opinion, the impact of statistical inference is often underestimated, even among so-called educated people. Could you provide a clear example of an important and high impact societal/political decision we based on statistical inference?

Comment: Tell them about clinical trials. Clinical trials rely entirely on the results of statistics.

Comment: social sciences: why are some many people spending so much effort on predicting the next elections outcome? http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9030.html

Answer (score 3):

Year 2013 was the international year of Statistics. Its sucessor, the [World of Statistics](http://www.worldofstatistics.org/), has plenty of resources on the power and impact of statistics on all aspects of society, including this [poster](http://www.worldofstatistics.org/wos/pdfs/StatsWorldPoster.pdf) and this [video](http://www.worldofstatistics.org/launch-video/).